# How to create an executable PrimeTime script?

Tags: verilog, hdl

When creating scripts for Synopsys PrimeTime, the tutorials I have found execute the scripts by loading the tool (pt_shell) then sourcing the script.

To run script:

```
pt_shell
source power.scr
```

Example Script:

```
#power.scr
set power_enable_analysis TRUE
set target_library "/home/syedh/iit_stdcells/lib/tsmc018/lib/iit018_stdcells.db"
set link_library "/home/syedh/iit_stdcells/lib/tsmc018/lib/iit018_stdcells.db *"

read_db $target_library
read_verilog top_syn.v
current_design top
link
read_vcd dmp_top.vcd -strip_path tb_top/uut
create_power_waveforms –output vcd

report_power
```

How do I make a executable script that will launch PrimeTime (pt_shell) and then run the commands?

Examples came from [here](https://computing.ece.vt.edu/wiki/Synopsys_Tutorial%3a_Power_Estimation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pt_shell -h` shows the `-file` option which may do what you need:

```
pt_shell -file power.scr
```

Comment: I have seen that put by itself in a bash script, which you then execute. I was hoping to have it all contained in one file.

Comment: I guess you could create a shell or Perl script which contains the contents of your `power.scr` file which writes out a temporary `power.scr` file, then calls `pt_shell -file power.scr`, then deletes `power.scr`.  But that seems a bit extreme just to avoid having 2 files.